# Search bar over google maps with ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, searchbar

I’m trying to place a search bar over google map in ionic 4, like the one you see in GoogleMaps app, but I can’t manage to show it.

This is my code:

```
  <ion-content #map id='map' >
      <ion-searchbar #searchBar></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-content>

#map {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;}

#searchBar {
display: block;
z-index: 999;
position: absolute;}
```

I’ve been playing with z-index and the position but it’s not working. Any clue on this?

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

I use this following code to place a search bar over google map by make  the ion-header transparent and use full screen ion-content.

In home.page.html

```
<ion-header  no-border  color="translucent">
</ion-header>
<ion-content fullscreen>
  <ion-toolbar slot="fixed" color="translucent" > 
    <ion-searchbar   color="light"  placeholder="Filter Schedules"></ion-searchbar>   
  </ion-toolbar>
  <div #map id="map">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

And my home.page.scss

```
 .header::after {
    background-image: none;
  }
  ion-toolbar {
    --background-color: transparent;
    --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
  }

#map {  
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

see if that helps

```
 <ion-content>
  <div #map id='map'></div>
  <ion-searchbar #searchBar></ion-searchbar>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gary, but that doesn't work, the searchbar doesn't appear.